# web scraping beautiful-soup returning JavaScript code

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape websites like indeed, but beautiful soup is returning me plain `JavaScript` code, I don't know whether I should use anything like *selenium* or beautiful-soup will do the job.

```
e.prototype=new Error,e.prototype.name="InvalidCharacterError",{btoa:t,atob:o}});}if (!("Date"in self&&"now"in self.Date&&"getTime"in self.Date.prototype
)) {Date.now=function e(){return(new Date).getTime()};}if (!("Date"in self&&"toISOString"in Date.prototype
)) {Date.prototype.toISOString=function t(){function t(t,e){return t=""+t,"0000".substr(0,e-t.length)+t}var e=this;return e.getUTCFullYear()+"-"+t(e.getUTCMonth()+1,2)+"-"+t(e.getUTCDate(),2)+"T"+t(e.getUTCHours(),2)+":"+t(e.getUTCMinutes(),2)+":"+t(e.getUTCSeconds(),2)+"."+t(e.getUTCMilliseconds(),3)+"Z"};}if (!("document"in self
)) {"undefined"==typeof WorkerGlobalScope&&"function"!=typeof importScripts&&(self.HTMLDocument?self.Document=self.HTMLDocument:(self.Document=self.HTMLDocument=document.constructor=new Function("return function Document() {}")(),self.Document.p
```

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i was not going through the page properly page was not fully dynamic,